# USB read only protection (fsck.fat 4.1 (2017-01-24) open: Read-only file system)

Tags: usb

I have one USB flash and can not write i it so i tried [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z9A1-NeXfJU) instruction and get this output:

```
root@so-notebook:~# df -Th
Filesystem     Type      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev           devtmpfs  5.8G     0  5.8G   0% /dev
tmpfs          tmpfs     1.2G  4.4M  1.2G   1% /run
/dev/sda4      ext4       91G   60G   27G  70% /
tmpfs          tmpfs     5.9G  162M  5.7G   3% /dev/shm
tmpfs          tmpfs     5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs          tmpfs     5.9G     0  5.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop1     squashfs   27M   27M     0 100% /snap/sickgear/844
/dev/loop2     squashfs  145M  145M     0 100% /snap/code/36
/dev/loop3     squashfs   55M   55M     0 100% /snap/core18/1754
/dev/loop0     squashfs  141M  141M     0 100% /snap/opera/80
/dev/loop4     squashfs  9.7M  9.7M     0 100% /snap/ktorrent/9
/dev/loop5     squashfs   30M   30M     0 100% /snap/node/2847
/dev/loop6     squashfs  1.0M  1.0M     0 100% /snap/gnome-logs/100
/dev/loop7     squashfs  179M  179M     0 100% /snap/arduino-mhall119/7
/dev/loop9     squashfs  129M  129M     0 100% /snap/deepin-voice-recorder/1
/dev/loop8     squashfs  290M  290M     0 100% /snap/kde-frameworks-5-qt-5-14-core18/3
/dev/loop10    squashfs   60M   60M     0 100% /snap/mockuuups/3
/dev/loop11    squashfs   61M   61M     0 100% /snap/zenkit-todo/5
/dev/loop12    squashfs  341M  341M     0 100% /snap/pycharm-community/202
/dev/loop13    squashfs  110M  110M     0 100% /snap/openscad-nightly/1842
/dev/loop14    squashfs  6.8M  6.8M     0 100% /snap/wireguard-ammp/95
/dev/loop15    squashfs  140M  140M     0 100% /snap/slack/24
/dev/loop17    squashfs  384K  384K     0 100% /snap/uboot-tools/3
/dev/loop18    squashfs  340M  340M     0 100% /snap/pycharm-community/197
/dev/loop16    squashfs  9.7M  9.7M     0 100% /snap/ktorrent/7
/dev/loop19    squashfs  142M  142M     0 100% /snap/inkscape/7601
/dev/loop20    squashfs  4.7M  4.7M     0 100% /snap/spreedme/22
/dev/loop21    squashfs  4.2M  4.2M     0 100% /snap/notepad-plus-plus/234
/dev/loop23    squashfs  161M  161M     0 100% /snap/opentoonz-morevna/72
/dev/loop24    squashfs  163M  163M     0 100% /snap/blender/40
/dev/loop22    squashfs   33M   33M     0 100% /snap/domotzpro-agent-publicstore/66
/dev/loop26    squashfs  8.0M  8.0M     0 100% /snap/pulsemixer/283
/dev/loop25    squashfs   26M   26M     0 100% /snap/heroku/3960
/dev/loop27    squashfs  115M  115M     0 100% /snap/signal-desktop/325
/dev/loop28    squashfs  708M  708M     0 100% /snap/android-studio/88
/dev/loop29    squashfs  230M  230M     0 100% /snap/qt513/18
/dev/loop30    squashfs  2.3M  2.3M     0 100% /snap/red-app/18
/dev/loop31    squashfs   64M   64M     0 100% /snap/vrew/138
/dev/loop32    squashfs   58M   58M     0 100% /snap/jdownloader2/10
/dev/loop33    squashfs   63M   63M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1506
/dev/loop37    squashfs  118M  118M     0 100% /snap/google-cloud-sdk/140
/dev/loop36    squashfs   29M   29M     0 100% /snap/chromium-ffmpeg/15
/dev/loop35    squashfs  106M  106M     0 100% /snap/deja-dup/350
/dev/loop39    squashfs  109M  109M     0 100% /snap/odrive-unofficial/2
/dev/loop34    squashfs  160M  160M     0 100% /snap/polar-bookshelf/85
/dev/loop38    squashfs  256M  256M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/36
/dev/loop42    squashfs  163M  163M     0 100% /snap/blender/41
/dev/loop43    squashfs   74M   74M     0 100% /snap/poddr/5
/dev/loop40    squashfs  188M  188M     0 100% /snap/clementine/659
/dev/loop41    squashfs  254M  254M     0 100% /snap/subsync/9
/dev/loop44    squashfs  227M  227M     0 100% /snap/wine-platform-runtime/136
/dev/loop45    squashfs  128K  128K     0 100% /snap/acrordrdc/8
/dev/loop46    squashfs  173M  173M     0 100% /snap/qt551/30
/dev/loop47    squashfs  8.7M  8.7M     0 100% /snap/nmap/823
/dev/loop49    squashfs   62M   62M     0 100% /snap/rocketchat-desktop/156
/dev/loop48    squashfs  107M  107M     0 100% /snap/yakyak/74
/dev/loop50    squashfs  185M  185M     0 100% /snap/eclipse/40
/dev/loop51    squashfs  141M  141M     0 100% /snap/opera/81
/dev/loop52    squashfs   30M   30M     0 100% /snap/node/2853
/dev/loop53    squashfs  2.5M  2.5M     0 100% /snap/gnome-calculator/730
/dev/loop54    squashfs   98M   98M     0 100% /snap/core/9289
/dev/loop56    squashfs   61M   61M     0 100% /snap/core20/634
/dev/loop55    squashfs  160M  160M     0 100% /snap/opentoonz/84
/dev/loop57    squashfs   54M   54M     0 100% /snap/telemetrytv/28
/dev/loop58    squashfs  2.5M  2.5M     0 100% /snap/gnome-calculator/748
/dev/loop59    squashfs   72M   72M     0 100% /snap/insomnia/69
/dev/loop60    squashfs  2.2M  2.2M     0 100% /snap/mosquitto/269
/dev/loop61    squashfs  152M  152M     0 100% /snap/arduino-mhall119/5
/dev/loop62    squashfs   20M   20M     0 100% /snap/okular/98
/dev/loop63    squashfs  164M  164M     0 100% /snap/postman/116
/dev/loop64    squashfs  2.9M  2.9M     0 100% /snap/utube/45
/dev/loop65    squashfs  2.2M  2.2M     0 100% /snap/mosquitto/298
/dev/loop67    squashfs  110M  110M     0 100% /snap/transitionsdj/13
/dev/loop70    squashfs  256K  256K     0 100% /snap/gtk2-common-themes/13
/dev/loop66    squashfs  118M  118M     0 100% /snap/google-cloud-sdk/139
/dev/loop71    squashfs  162M  162M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/128
/dev/loop69    squashfs  141M  141M     0 100% /snap/mathpix-snipping-tool/104
/dev/loop68    squashfs  8.0M  8.0M     0 100% /snap/pulsemixer/250
/dev/loop72    squashfs   74M   74M     0 100% /snap/alexaweb/1
/dev/loop73    squashfs   87M   87M     0 100% /snap/shotcut/67
/dev/loop74    squashfs   87M   87M     0 100% /snap/shotcut/64
/dev/loop76    squashfs  129M  129M     0 100% /snap/meshlab/5
/dev/loop77    squashfs   63M   63M     0 100% /snap/telegram-desktop/1671
/dev/loop75    squashfs   74M   74M     0 100% /snap/wine-platform-3-stable/6
/dev/loop78    squashfs  1.4M  1.4M     0 100% /snap/anifx/21
/dev/loop79    squashfs  254M  254M     0 100% /snap/subsync/10
/dev/loop80    squashfs   64M   64M     0 100% /snap/vrew/139
/dev/loop82    squashfs  2.8M  2.8M     0 100% /snap/telegram-cli/25
/dev/loop81    squashfs  291M  291M     0 100% /snap/vlc/1620
/dev/loop83    squashfs   12M   12M     0 100% /snap/hangups/142
/dev/loop85    squashfs   55M   55M     0 100% /snap/core18/1705
/dev/loop84    squashfs   59M   59M     0 100% /snap/kesty-whatsapp/35
/dev/loop89    squashfs   14M   14M     0 100% /snap/tor-middle-relay/277
/dev/loop88    squashfs  230M  230M     0 100% /snap/qt513/19
/dev/loop87    squashfs   33M   33M     0 100% /snap/node-red/590
/dev/loop91    squashfs  142M  142M     0 100% /snap/inkscape/7627
/dev/loop90    squashfs  384K  384K     0 100% /snap/gnome-characters/550
/dev/loop86    squashfs  1.8G  1.8G     0 100% /snap/webots/14
/dev/loop92    squashfs  2.3M  2.3M     0 100% /snap/red-app/19
/dev/loop96    squashfs  5.2M  5.2M     0 100% /snap/rclone-dev/16
/dev/loop95    squashfs   61M   61M     0 100% /snap/translatium/63
/dev/loop94    squashfs  233M  233M     0 100% /snap/nextcloud/20498
/dev/loop93    squashfs  102M  102M     0 100% /snap/p7zip-desktop/220
/dev/loop98    squashfs  173M  173M     0 100% /snap/qt551/29
/dev/loop97    squashfs   33M   33M     0 100% /snap/domotzpro-agent-publicstore/69
/dev/loop101   squashfs  4.0M  4.0M     0 100% /snap/notepad-plus-plus/232
/dev/loop99    squashfs   19M   19M     0 100% /snap/ike-qt/7
/dev/loop100   squashfs  227M  227M     0 100% /snap/wine-platform-runtime/145
/dev/loop102   squashfs   95M   95M     0 100% /snap/google-play-music-desktop-player/80
/dev/loop106   squashfs   61M   61M     0 100% /snap/mockuuups/5
/dev/loop104   squashfs   83M   83M     0 100% /snap/ultimate-media-downloader/3
/dev/loop105   squashfs  215M  215M     0 100% /snap/wine-platform-5-stable/4
/dev/loop107   squashfs   45M   45M     0 100% /snap/filezilla/17
/dev/loop103   squashfs  139M  139M     0 100% /snap/kdictionary/2
/dev/loop109   squashfs  145M  145M     0 100% /snap/code/35
/dev/loop110   squashfs  4.5M  4.5M     0 100% /snap/ormesh/12
/dev/loop108   squashfs  134M  134M     0 100% /snap/projectlibre/3
/dev/loop111   squashfs  8.7M  8.7M     0 100% /snap/nmap/1356
/dev/loop112   squashfs  236M  236M     0 100% /snap/kde-frameworks-5/27
/dev/loop113   squashfs   54M   54M     0 100% /snap/telemetrytv/27
/dev/loop117   squashfs  1.0M  1.0M     0 100% /snap/gnome-logs/93
/dev/loop116   squashfs   62M   62M     0 100% /snap/rocketchat-desktop/157
/dev/loop114   squashfs   55M   55M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1502
/dev/loop115   squashfs   44M   44M     0 100% /snap/riseup-vpn/159
/dev/loop119   squashfs  211M  211M     0 100% /snap/eclipse/48
/dev/loop121   squashfs  261M  261M     0 100% /snap/kde-frameworks-5-core18/32
/dev/loop118   squashfs   68M   68M     0 100% /snap/superproductivity/673
/dev/loop123   squashfs  204M  204M     0 100% /snap/cloudcompare/205
/dev/loop122   squashfs  279M  279M     0 100% /snap/octave/30
/dev/loop120   squashfs  801M  801M     0 100% /snap/android-studio/90
/dev/loop124   squashfs  110M  110M     0 100% /snap/odio/5
/dev/loop125   squashfs  164M  164M     0 100% /snap/postman/115
/dev/loop126   squashfs   61M   61M     0 100% /snap/translatium/62
/dev/loop127   squashfs   59M   59M     0 100% /snap/kesty-whatsapp/37
/dev/loop129   squashfs  384K  384K     0 100% /snap/micropython/80
/dev/loop128   squashfs  256M  256M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/33
/dev/loop131   squashfs  215M  215M     0 100% /snap/wine-platform-5-stable/5
/dev/loop130   squashfs  5.9M  5.9M     0 100% /snap/tor/2
/dev/loop135   squashfs   41M   41M     0 100% /snap/telegram-testbart/3
/dev/loop132   squashfs  188M  188M     0 100% /snap/arduino/32
/dev/loop141   squashfs  1.9M  1.9M     0 100% /snap/uconfig/118
/dev/loop142   squashfs   77M   77M     0 100% /snap/insomnia/74
/dev/loop134   squashfs   68M   68M     0 100% /snap/superproductivity/686
/dev/loop146   squashfs   20M   20M     0 100% /snap/okular/90
/dev/loop133   squashfs  160M  160M     0 100% /snap/opentoonz/94
/dev/loop152   squashfs   27M   27M     0 100% /snap/minuet/49
/dev/loop138   squashfs   60M   60M     0 100% /snap/youtubeport/5
/dev/loop150   squashfs  2.3M  2.3M     0 100% /snap/gnome-system-monitor/145
/dev/loop144   squashfs  384K  384K     0 100% /snap/gnome-characters/539
/dev/loop153   squashfs  161M  161M     0 100% /snap/opentoonz-morevna/77
/dev/loop136   squashfs   61M   61M     0 100% /snap/mtpaint-casept/1
/dev/loop157   squashfs  2.9M  2.9M     0 100% /snap/utube/46
/dev/loop154   squashfs  2.3M  2.3M     0 100% /snap/gnome-system-monitor/148
/dev/loop143   squashfs  165M  165M     0 100% /snap/polar-bookshelf/86
/dev/loop158   squashfs  144M  144M     0 100% /snap/gydl/2
/dev/loop148   squashfs   97M   97M     0 100% /snap/core/9436
/dev/loop140   squashfs   98M   98M     0 100% /snap/uconfig/112
/dev/loop156   squashfs  141M  141M     0 100% /snap/mathpix-snipping-tool/155
/dev/loop166   squashfs  374M  374M     0 100% /snap/anbox/186
/dev/loop164   squashfs  124M  124M     0 100% /snap/krita/55
/dev/loop162   squashfs  161M  161M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/116
/dev/loop147   squashfs  136M  136M     0 100% /snap/cloudcompare/200
/dev/loop139   squashfs   27M   27M     0 100% /snap/sickgear/850
/dev/loop170   squashfs  114M  114M     0 100% /snap/audacity/666
/dev/loop151   squashfs  142M  142M     0 100% /snap/arduino/41
/dev/loop174   squashfs   44M   44M     0 100% /snap/riseup-vpn/161
/dev/loop167   squashfs  400M  400M     0 100% /snap/mycroft/463
/dev/loop168   squashfs  126M  126M     0 100% /snap/krita/57
/dev/loop180   squashfs  8.5M  8.5M     0 100% /snap/sprinkle/2
/dev/loop137   squashfs  103M  103M     0 100% /snap/deja-dup/344
/dev/loop161   squashfs  115M  115M     0 100% /snap/signal-desktop/324
/dev/loop159   squashfs  2.0M  2.0M     0 100% /snap/fast/4
/dev/loop145   squashfs   33M   33M     0 100% /snap/node-red/595
/dev/loop160   squashfs   96M   96M     0 100% /snap/yakyak/70
/dev/loop155   squashfs   26M   26M     0 100% /snap/heroku/3947
/dev/loop185   squashfs   58M   58M     0 100% /snap/jdownloader2/9
/dev/loop163   squashfs  110M  110M     0 100% /snap/openscad-nightly/1851
/dev/loop184   squashfs  291M  291M     0 100% /snap/vlc/1700
/dev/loop169   squashfs   16M   16M     0 100% /snap/telega/24
/dev/loop179   squashfs  6.0M  6.0M     0 100% /snap/wireguard-ammp/72
/dev/loop172   squashfs  152M  152M     0 100% /snap/telegram-desktop/1708
/dev/loop149   squashfs   88M   88M     0 100% /snap/meshlab-mardy/5
/dev/loop181   squashfs  219M  219M     0 100% /snap/nextcloud/20007
/dev/loop165   squashfs  195M  195M     0 100% /snap/clementine/890
/dev/loop171   squashfs  256K  256K     0 100% /snap/gtk2-common-themes/9
/dev/loop177   squashfs  131M  131M     0 100% /snap/meshlab/6
/dev/loop173   squashfs  129M  129M     0 100% /snap/deepin-music/1
/dev/loop178   squashfs  276M  276M     0 100% /snap/octave/29
/dev/loop175   squashfs  102M  102M     0 100% /snap/zenkit-todo/3
/dev/loop182   squashfs  114M  114M     0 100% /snap/audacity/675
/dev/loop186   squashfs  145M  145M     0 100% /snap/slack/25
/dev/loop176   squashfs  291M  291M     0 100% /snap/kde-frameworks-5-qt-5-14-core18/4
/dev/loop188   squashfs  1.3M  1.3M     0 100% /snap/tinc-vpn/2
/dev/loop187   squashfs  110M  110M     0 100% /snap/transitionsdj/14
/dev/loop183   squashfs   27M   27M     0 100% /snap/minuet/55
/dev/sda3      ext4      197G  181G  5.8G  97% /home
tmpfs          tmpfs     1.2G   48K  1.2G   1% /run/user/1000
/dev/sdb1      vfat       30G   26G  3.8G  88% /media/so/BCC0-8F42
root@so-notebook:~# umount /media/so/BCC0-8F42
root@so-notebook:~# dosfsck -a /dev/sdb1
fsck.fat 4.1 (2017-01-24)
open: Read-only file system
```

Thanks.

Comment: Hardware R/W switch on the flash?

Comment: Watch `sudo journalctl  -f` as you plug it in.